# Start new Intent from RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I have **RecyclerViewAdapter** :

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {



    private List<Cards> items;
    private int itemLayout;


    Context context;

    public RecycleViewAdapter(List<Cards> items, int itemLayout) {

        this.items = items;
        this.itemLayout= itemLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

       View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


        Cards item=items.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item.getName());
        String cardvalue = item.getCountry();
        String cardCode = item.getCode();
        String cardCountry = item.getCountry();


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return items.size();
    }
    public static class  MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView title;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);

            title.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    }
}
```

and I need to start new Intent (**OnCardsSelected.class**)  , but I cant add this line to my method `onClick`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, OnCardSelected.class);
```

I don't understand whats I do wrong, I just need to start Intent and put some information to this intent, I read some manuals but didn't understand  theirs explanation so I hope u will help me .Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Probably trying to start Activity from `onClick` method then use `v.getContext()` instead of `this`(*which refer to onClick method context*) as first parameter to Intent constructor :

```
Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), OnCardSelected.class);
```

Comment: thanks, is works, and another question , what code i write to send Strings(cardValue,cardCode,cardCountry) to another activity. I know that this is  intent.putExtra (key , string) but i cant put strings from my onBindViewHolder , explain me please

Comment: @Ololoking: Use `holder.title.setTag(item)` in `onBindViewHolder` then use `Cards cards=(Cards)v.getTag()` inside onClick. get values from cards like `String cardvalue = cards.getCountry();String cardCode = cards.getCode();String cardCountry = cards.getCountry();`

Answer (score 5):

Add this line of code in your onBindViewHolder method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), YourClassName.class);
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: For good readability of your code you might want to write it this was.
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Destination.class);
v.getContext().startActivity(intent).


Where v is the the object of the View class.

Answer (score 4):

```
public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context,List<Cards> items, int itemLayout) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.itemLayout= itemLayout;
}
...
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
mContext.startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), NewOnCLickAccount.class);
            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can save someone, especialy one with different activities to open for each item click. I was in same situation.

1. Create a model class (or restructure your old one) to add Intent . Here is my example.

```
Class SampleModel{
String sampleString;
Intent sampleIntent;

public SampleModel(String sampleString, Intent sampleIntent){

this.sampleString = sampleString;
this.sampleIntent = sampleIntent;

}

//add getters
}
```

2. In your recyclerview adapter add Context (let's call it sampleContext) and ArrayList (lets call it list)that will carry your model.
3. In your onBindViewHolder

```
SampleModel model = list.get(position);

//inside holder.viewclick setOnClickListner, here we open intent
sampleContext.starActivity(model.getIntent);
```

4. The rest is just like normal recyclerview process. i.e

```
SampleModel model = new SampleModel ("sample text", new Intent(this, "AnotherActivity.class));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of me using an OnClickListener inside the adapter's BindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHolder holder, int position) {

    Item playerItem = (Item) itemList.get(position);

    itemName = playerItem.getName();
    itemPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    itemHolder = holder;

    //Sets Text
    holder.name.setText(itemName);

    //holder.playerName.setTag(R.string.listSize, playerList.size());
    holder.name.setTag(position);

    //holder.image.setImageAlpha(playerItem.getImage());
    holder.image.setImageResource(playerItem.getImage());
    holder.image.setTag(position);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //goes to new activity passing the item name
            Intent intent = new Intent(itemHolder.itemView.getContext(), MapActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            //get text for current item
            String textGet = itemName;
            //put text into a bundle and add to intent
            intent.putExtra("text", textGet);

            //get position to carry integer
            intent.putExtra("position", itemPosition);

            intent.putExtras(b);

            //begin activity
            itemHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: getting this error "ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent"

Comment: Did you put this code inside a custom adapter? Also which line did the error come up? I am guessing the "intent = new intent" line?

Comment: yes , itemHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

Comment: Of course I assume you changed MapActivity.class to your own class, is the activity added to the manifest? Also are you trying to open anything other than an ordinary activity?

Answer (score -1):

You already Passing the Context into the adapter. Therefore inside the onBindViewHolder() you can create the intent.

`Intent intent = new Intent(context,OnCardsSelected.class);
context.startActivity(intent);`